# C++ Operator<< Overloading to Print Member Variable Values

Tags: c++11, vector, printing, iterator, operator-overloading

All -- I have checked existing discussion topics and/or questions on this, and none seems to address this. Hence posting this question. Happy to be referred to an existing link that might already be addressing this exact issue, if I overlooked it.

Below is my snippet of code:

```
class MyBook{
  public:
    MyBook(): bidPrices(10, 0.0),
              askPrices(10, 0.0),
              bidSizes(10, 0),
              askSizes(10, 0) {}
    std::vector<double> bidPrices;
    std::vector<double> askPrices;
    std::vector<int> bidSizes;
    std::vector<int> askSizes;
};

// Forward declaration
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<MyBook>> myBookMap;

// Overload << to print.

std::ostream&* operator<<(std::ostream& os, MyBook& mbk)
{
  os << "bid price: " << mbk.bidPrices[0] <<  " "
     << "bid size: " << mbk.bidSizes[0] <<  " "
     << "ask price: " << mbk.askPrices[0] <<  " "
     << "ask size: " << mbk.askSizes[0] << endl;
  return os;
}
```

Later inside main():

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<MyBook>>::iterator it = myBookMap.begin();
while (it != myBookMap.end())
{
  std::cout << it->first;
  std::cout << it->second;
}
```

At compile time, I see "error: no match for 'operator<<'" error.

It possibly couldn't be because of the differing data types between sizes and prices, and even if it is that, I don't see how I can use a template for that when I am passing in the object (mbk) as opposed to a vector (int vector vs. double vector) as the argument to the operator<< overloading function.

Thanks for any insights. Happy to be crucified, although I'm still a newbie.

Best wishes.

Comment: Does it even compile? Because you say you are returning a reference to a pointer, but then you go with `return os`, where `os` is `std::ostream& os`. I don't think it's convertible to a pointer. It is expected for the `operator<<` to return a reference to the stream, so you can chain calls. If you somehow return a pointer in the chain, you might very well receive an error that `operator<<` on the pointer is not defined.

Comment: You need to use `*` dereference operator to get `MyBook` stored by unique_ptr, `std::cout << it->second;` should be `std::cout << *it->second;`.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out. Schoolboy error. The value was a pointer to object, hence should be. This compiles fine.

```
std::cout << *it->second;
```